# How are symmetries defined mathematically?

Tags: differential-geometry, conservation-laws, group-theory, noethers-theorem, lie-algebra

I have started working on differential geometry very recently. I am little bit familiar with mathematical concepts such as manifolds, differential forms and associated concepts. As I was speeding through I caught interest in Lie groups and whose invaluable connection with the symmetries. I would be happy if anybody answers to these few questions.

1. I want to know what is a symmetry from the mathematical point of view?
2. How are $su2$, $su3$, and other symmetries first formulated?
3. What was the motivation?
4. How do we identify internal symmetries and corresponding conserved physical quantities?

Comment: Have you read much about [Noether's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether's_theorem)?

Comment: I haven't worked out the theorem yet but I understand what it says.